# Find the system's line terminator

Tags: c++, c, header, newline

Is there a header file somewhere that stores the line termination character/s for the system (so that without any `#ifdef`s it will work on all platforms, MAC, Windows, Linux, etc)?

Comment: Are you talking about std::endl?

Comment: just use `\n`. that's what text mode is for. even though it's an abomination, it addresses just the problem of doing system-independent line endings

Comment: @alf `\n` doesn't work on all systems

Comment: @Caesar can I convert std::endl to a string?

Comment: @Caesar: which system did you have in mind? it works even on system where lines *don't* have terminators.

Comment: @MSalters where is textmode (how do I open a file as text?)

Comment: @Caesar - `'\n'` has been part of C for at least 40 years. What systems doesn't it work on?

Comment: @soandos: `std::ifstream myInputFile(filename)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because it's `\n` everywhere. That expands to the correct newline character(s) when you write it to a text file.

Comment: @soandos: that's also taken care of by the standard lib (and is a main reason why text mode is an abomination: it interferes with byte counts at the wrong level)

Comment: Same thing. All lines read from a text file are separated by `\n`.

Comment: How can I open a file as text mode?

Comment: @soandos: text mode is default. Just don't ask for binary mode.

Comment: @Fred text mode is ghastly. Just always ask for binary mode.

Comment: @NicholasWilson: It may be ghastly, but it's how you get platform-native line endings. You can write your text to a binary file, but it won't look very nice if you open it in Notepad.

Answer (score 6):

You should open the file in "text mode" (that is "not use binary"), and newline is always `'\n'`, whatever the native file is. The C library will translate whatever native character(s) indicate newlines into `'\n'` whenever appropriate [that is, reading/writing text files]. Note that this also means you can't rely on "counting the number of characters read and using that to "seek back to this location".

If the file is binary, then newlines aren't newlines anyways.

And unless you plan on running on really ancient systems, and you REALLY want to do this, I would do:

```
#ifdef __WINDOWS__    // Or something like that
#define END_LINE    "\r\n"
#else
#define END_LINE    "\n"
#endif
```

This won't work for MacOS before MacOS X, but surely nobody is using pre-MacOS X hardware any longer?

Comment: How can I open a file in text mode (no `#ifdef`s please, see question)?

Comment: But what if I, say, read HTTP packets from a Berkeley socket?

Comment: By NOT specifying that the file is binary!

Comment: If you are using sockets, I guess you won't know what is at the other end, so you have to look for either of `'\r'`, `'\n'` and in case of `'\r'`, check if the next character is `'\n'` - if so, remove that from the stream. I think reading streams is done based on file-descriptors, not C library "FILE" anyways.

Comment: @Joker_vD: HTTP uses `\r\n`. Not platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's anything in the standard library to obtain the current platform's line terminator.

The closest looking API is

```
char_type  std::basic_ios::widen(char c);
```

It "converts a character c to its equivalent in the current locale" ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/widen)). I was pointed at it by the documentation for `std::endl` which "inserts a endline character into the output sequence os and flushes it as if by calling `os.put(os.widen('\n'))` followed by `os.flush()`" ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)).

On Posix,

- `widen('\n')` returns `'\n'` (as a `char`, for `char`-based streams);
- `endl` inserts a `'\n'` and flushes the buffer.

On Windows, they do exactly the same. In fact

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ofstream f;
    f.open("aaa.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
    f << "aaa" << endl << "bbb";
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

will result in a file with just `'\n'` as a line terminator.

As others have suggested, when the file is open in *text mode* (the default) the `'\n'` will be automatically converted to `'\r' '\n'` on Windows.

(I've rewritten this answer because I had incorrectly assumed that `std::endl` translated to `"\r\n"` on Windows)

Comment: @Cheers, thanks for spotting my (terrible) mistake - I've done some research and I've completely rewritten the answer as I believe it could clarify what `endl` actually does.

Answer (score 1):

Posix requires it to be \n. So if _POSIX_VERSION is defined, it's \n. Otherwise, special-case the only non-POSIX OS, windows, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be extended a little further by being able to use the same code to read both Windows-based text files and Unix-based text files in Windows, MacOS and Linux/Unix systems (excluding the ancient Macintosh system that use `\r` as line delimiter).

As already pointed out by others, `\n` can be used as line delimiter in all above systems because underlying C library can convert it to native delimiter used by each system. Therefore, one can use the following codes to read in text files that use either `\n` or `\r\n` as line delimiters while discarding all delimiter characters:

```cpp
// Open a file in text mode
std::ifstream file_stream(file_name, ios_base::in);
// Use widened '\n' as line delimiter
for(std::string text_line; std::getline(file_stream, text_line, input.widen('\n'));)
{
    if(!text_line.empty())
    {
        // Discard '\r' when read Windows-based file in Unix-like systems
        if(text_line.back() == '\r') text_line.pop_back();
        // Do more with text_line
    }
}
```

In above codes, read-in lines containing `\r` will only be encountered when reading Windows-based text files in Unix-like systems because a single `\n` is used as delimiter while Windows-based text files use `\r\n`. On the other hand, when reading text files in Windows-based systems, text files with either `\r\n` or `\n` can be removed by `std::getline` function that uses the widened `\n` as delimiter. Note that this code snippet doesn't remove any `\r` not adjacent to `\n` because then those text files are not correctly formed in Windows, Mac and Linux/Unix systems.